# If javascript is disabled in phone settings, will phonegap + jquerymobile app works?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

If javascript is disabled in phone settings, will phonegap + jquerymobile app works?
Possible to display a error message or such to user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If javascript is disabled in phone settings, will phonegap + jquerymobile app works?

No

> Possible to display a error message or such to user?

Use a [noscript](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#edef-NOSCRIPT) element.

Pages for the general web should always be functional without script. They might not have all the bells and whistles, but they should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<noscript></noscript>` tags to include content when JavaScript is not enabled. Most likely it won't work, since anything dynamic or web-appy relies on JavaScript being there.

Comment: The content in noscript elements is always incldued, it just isn't shown when script is enabled.